# Graph API: How to get albums in right order?

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing application using **Graph API**. It reads page's **photo albums**, but they are returned ordered by time they were uploaded even though their **order was changed** on Facebook by page admin (drag & drop style).

Is there any possibility to get albums ordered as admin intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/ nor http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/album/ expose a sort order field.  I'd suggest filing a bug at http://developers.facebook.com/bugs and hope facebook thinks it's cool enough to include in a future release.